# Rails Angular js application.js not pulling in scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, input

Trying to set up a very simple rails angularJs application where an input field's text is outputed on the page.

I don't think my application.js file is pulling in the correct dependencies, because my main.js is not firing.

Created new rails called "stockwatch", then a new controller "rails g controller watchlist index"

I included "gem 'angularjs-rails'" in my Gemfile and did "bundle install"

Other files updated:

stockwatch/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require main.js
//= require_tree ./angular
//= require_tree .
```

stockwatch/app/assets/javascripts/main.js:

```
var app = angular.module("Stockwatch", ['ngResource']);
```

stockwatch/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='Stockwatch'>
...
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

stockwatch/app/views/watchlist/index.html/erb:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model='newSymbol' placeholder="Enter a symbol">
</form>
{{ newSymbol }}
```

and finally I added "root 'watchlist#index'" to my stockwatch/config/routes.fb file.

Viewing the app just shows {{newSymbol}} without updating it based on the input. Have tried multiple different variables and defining modules in main.js. I think the problem is that application.js is not pulling in main.js

I tried putting an alert statement in main.js but no result. Is there anything else I need to add to application.js to trigger main.js?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried putting main.js after `//= require_tree ./angular`

Comment: I did everything you mentioned and it works fine for me. Have you tried using your browser's developer console to see what you scripts files being fetched? Are you testing this in production mode or development mode? Are you testing this using precompiled js? Did you run assets:precompile?

Answer (score 0):

I added "<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>" into the application.html.erb. Didn't know that I needed that, so no javascript was getting pulled in. Thanks everyone who took a look.